# Subir solo videos al servidor con Php y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Actualmente quiero subir solo videos al servidor validando desde php:

Esto es lo que llevo actualmente:

```
<?php
session_start();
require'funcs/conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

<?php
  $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id_usuario']);
  $peticion = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$usuario'";
  $conecta = $mysqli->query($peticion);
  $row = $conecta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<?php   

require 'funcs/conexion.php';
require 'perfil/valida_video.php';

$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$descripcion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['descripcion']);

$id_insert = $id;

if(isNull($descripcion)) {
        $errors[] = "No puede dejar el campo Descripcion vacio";
        }
        if(count($errors) == 0)
    {
if($_FILES["archivo"] ["error"]>0) {
                echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>No hubo cambios</h3></center>";
                header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            } else {
               $permitidos = array("video/mp4", "video/mpg", "video/mpeg", "video/avi");
               $limite_kb = 200000;

            if (in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {
            $ruta = 'galeria_video/'.$id_insert.'/';
            $archivo = utf8_decode($ruta.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);

            if(!file_exists($ruta)) {
                mkdir($ruta);
            }

            $nombre_archivo = "archivo_subido.mp4";
            $nombre_archivo = uniqid().".mp4";
            $archivo = $ruta . $nombre_archivo; 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (usuario, fecha, archivo, descripcion) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?)";
            $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                if ($statement) {
            $statement->bind_param("iss", $usuario, $archivo, $descripcion);
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->close();

            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)) {

            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

            if($resultado){
                echo "<h3><font color='#2ecc71'><center>Video Actualizado</h3></center>";
                header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            } else {
            echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>Error al guardar archivo</h3></center>";
                header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            }               

            } else {
            echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>Archivo ya existe</h3></center>";
            header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            }               

            } else {
              echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>Archivo no permitido o excede el tama&ntilde;o</h3></center>";
              header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);

            }
            }
    }
}            
?>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['nombre']?></h3>
        </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="archivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Archivo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="archivo">
                    <br>    
                </div>
            </div>
                <label for="archivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Agrega la descripcion de tu video</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" required>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <br>
                    <a href="perfil1.php?id_usuario=<?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>

                    <button type = "submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form> 
        <?php echo resultBlock($errors); ?>
    </div>
```

El problema esta en que no me guarda nada y me arroja el mensaje **No hubo cambios**.

No se porque no guarda la ruta.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error se refiere, de acuerdo a tu código, a que tienes un error al acceder al archivo que intentas cargar, por favor sustituye tu código actual por el siguiente, en el que imprimo en pantalla info sobre el error, para que puedas detectar cuál es y a partir de ahí solucionarlo. Probablemente estés excediendo algún parámetro de PHP como el límite de carga de archivos, el límite memoria o algo así.

```
<?php
session_start();
require'funcs/conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

<?php
  $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id_usuario']);
  $peticion = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$usuario'";
  $conecta = $mysqli->query($peticion);
  $row = $conecta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<?php   

require 'funcs/conexion.php';
require 'perfil/valida_video.php';

$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$descripcion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['descripcion']);

$id_insert = $id;

if(isNull($descripcion)) {
        $errors[] = "No puede dejar el campo Descripcion vacio";
        }
        if(count($errors) == 0)
    {
if($_FILES["archivo"] ["error"]>0) {
                echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>No hubo cambios</h3></center>";
                echo "<h1><font color='green'><center>ESTE ES EL ERROR</h1></center>";
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($_FILES["archivo"] ["error"]);
                echo "</pre>";
                header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            } else {
               $permitidos = array("video/mp4", "video/mpg", "video/mpeg", "video/avi");
               $limite_kb = 200000;

            if (in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {
            $ruta = 'galeria_video/'.$id_insert.'/';
            $archivo = utf8_decode($ruta.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);

            if(!file_exists($ruta)) {
                mkdir($ruta);
            }

            $nombre_archivo = "archivo_subido.mp4";
            $nombre_archivo = uniqid().".mp4";
            $archivo = $ruta . $nombre_archivo; 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (usuario, fecha, archivo, descripcion) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?)";
            $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                if ($statement) {
            $statement->bind_param("iss", $usuario, $archivo, $descripcion);
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->close();

            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)) {

            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

            if($resultado){
                echo "<h3><font color='#2ecc71'><center>Video Actualizado</h3></center>";
                header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            } else {
            echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>Error al guardar archivo</h3></center>";
                header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            }               

            } else {
            echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>Archivo ya existe</h3></center>";
            header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);
            }               

            } else {
              echo "<h3><font color='red'><center>Archivo no permitido o excede el tama&ntilde;o</h3></center>";
              header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria_video.php?id_usuario=".$_POST['id']);

            }
            }
    }
}            
?>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['nombre']?></h3>
        </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="archivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Archivo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="archivo">
                    <br>    
                </div>
            </div>
                <label for="archivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Agrega la descripcion de tu video</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" required>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <br>
                    <a href="perfil1.php?id_usuario=<?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>

                    <button type = "submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form> 
        <?php echo resultBlock($errors); ?>
    </div>
```